# Outlook Web-addins - SSO token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, outlook-web-addins

I'm in the process of creating a web add-in for Outlook. Outlook server is on exchange. I want to fetch data from Microsoft Graph in my add-on.

- I have registered applications in Azure AD according to this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet
- I edited the manifest according to this template:

  ```xml
  <WebApplicationInfo>
       <Id>Enter_client_ID_here</Id>
    <Resource>api://localhost:44355/Enter_client_ID_here</Resource>
    <Scopes>
          <Scope>Files.Read</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>
          <Scope>openid</Scope>
    </Scopes>
  </WebApplicationInfo>
  ```
- I added a code in the script that should download a token that I could use to authenticate myself with Graph:

```js
    Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function (result) {
        if (result.status === 'succeeded') {
            // Use this token to call Web API
            var ssoToken = result.value

        } else {
            if (result.error.code === 13003) {
                // SSO is not supported for domain user accounts, only
                // work or school (Office 365) or Microsoft Account IDs.
                console.log(result.error)
            } else {
                // Handle error
                console.log(result.error)
            }
        }
    })
```

Unfortunately, when downloading the token, it throws an error with code 13006. In the documentation, I don't understand how I could fix it. Does anyone know how to do this? Maybe I missed something.

The office add-in web project is in .NET Framework 4.8

I tried refreshing the page (as the documentation suggested) but it didn't help.

**EDIT**

I was able to get the access token but when I try to get something from Microsoft Graph I get a 401 error. Code below:

```js
const accessToken = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowSignInPrompt: true })

const me = await axios.get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
})
```

Have I made a mistake?

Comment: What Outlook client and version are you seeing this on?

There is documentation for error codes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins, including code 13006, does that help?

Comment: On the Outlook web client. I can't deduce anything from this documentation about this code.

Comment: As per the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins - to handle error code 13006, the logic implemented in the add-in code should ask the user to sign out and then restart the Office browser session. Could you please specify if you're looking for any particular detail in this regard.

Comment: Ok, but why does this problem appear with the desktop application?

Comment: It looks like you are using "Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync". Can you try using "OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken". If it does not resolve your issue can you try passing "allowSignInPrompt" argument as true? For more details please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#add-client-side-code

Comment: So I tried that method as well and it had the same effect.

Comment: Do you see this error with allowSignInPrompt param set to true as well? Does this error occur in all platofrms Win32, Outlook on Web and Mac?

Comment: Is it possible to share your test addin so that we can try to repro this at our end? Also can you try different scope in manifest for example <Scope>user.read</Scope>
<Scope>mail.read</Scope>
<Scope>profile</Scope>

Comment: I was able to get the access token but when I try to get something from Microsoft Graph I get a 401 error. Code in the post above.

Comment: The token obtained using getAccessToken API should be used to initiate a On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) to request a new access token with permissions to Microsoft Graph. Please refer to the documentation to understand more about how this flow works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph#how-it-works-at-runtime

Comment: Yes, it helped. I made a server that mediates between the client and the Graph. Thank you for your help.